# How to implement a sequence of text input dialogs?

Tags: android, input, dialog, control-flow

I am creating an android app and I would like to have a function that creates two text input dialogs one after the other and then performs an operation based on the values. Because everything in android is done asynchronously, I have come up with the following approach:

```
private void doOperation() {
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    showInput("Title", "Enter param1:", input, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            doOperation2(input.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

private void doOperation2(String param1) {
    if(/* Some condition on param1. */)
        return;
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    showInput("Title", "Enter param2:", input, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            doOperation3(param1, input.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

private void doOperation3(String param1, String param2) {
    actuallyDoOperation();
}

private void showInput(String title, String message, final EditText input, DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveActionListener) {
    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setMessage(message);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.ok), positiveActionListener);
    alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

This looks kind of messy to me, is there a better/nicer/cleaner/more correct way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to use two dialogs? `doOperation2(...)` doesn't actually do anything conditionally based on the return value from `doOperation1(...)`. Why don't you simply have both `TextView`s in one dialog?

Comment: Sorry, I left out code that wasn't fully relevant, have updated. I check the first parameter before displaying the second dialog.